# Construct Matrix from vectors

Tags: matrix, vector

I have to vectors

```
X={1,0,0};
Y={0,0,1};
```

and I would like to find the easiest way to construct the matrix 3x2 whose first column is X and second column is Y.

Comment: `Transpose[Join[{X}, {Y}]]`?

Comment: Perfect, thank you

Comment: ...also   `Transpose[{X, Y}]` and `Thread[{X, Y}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways, but "the right way" is

```
Transpose[{X,Y}]
```

It is compact and [does not unpack](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array).